# CalendarExtender in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, calendar

I am using a `CalendarExtender` control in my ASP.NET web application. I want to disable this control while clicking inside a text box. I am also using `HtmlEditor` (AJAX control toolkit) inside the same web page and I have only one script manager. I have done the following coding in order to get a `CalendarExtender` in a text box.

When I compile the program I don't get any errors, but when I click inside a text box the `CalendarExtender` does not appear on the web page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="before_adm.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
.
.
.
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox3">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

In web.config

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Where am I going wrong? How will I get a `CalendarExtender` on click in a textbox.

Comment: do you have a scriptmanager on the page?

Comment: Yes i have a scriptmanager on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have already gone through [Calendar Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar_Simple.ashx). Even if you have gone through, I would say just compare with that reference and you code to check what is missing?

Another thing would be copy paste their code in your project and then see if it is still working. If it is not working then you are missing some kind of config in your project and it is working then you are missing something in your page level coding.

PS: I would have tried your sample but as of now I don't have Ajax toolkit configured in my machine.

Comment: thank you very much. I copy pasted and tried bu the same problem, NO error and NO output!

Comment: Use Firefox and Firebug add-on. See if Firebug is telling any problem with JS setup or something like that.